# Gradle: How to exclude JAR from a WAR?

Tags: java, jar, gradle, war

I have a multi-project Gradle build structure, where child project depends on a JAR, which I don't want to be in WAR file. I tried "exclude" but it does not work.

The main project script:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
war {
    dependencies {
        runtime (project(':childProject')) {
            exclude group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', module: 'jsp-api'
        }
    }
}
```

The childProject script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile 'javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api'
}
```

Comment: I don't think that excludes are supported for project dependencies. (See John's answer for a working solution.) The `dependencies` block is a top-level element, and should not be nested inside `war`.

Answer (score 28):

I'm doing it this way.

```
war {   
    rootSpec.exclude("**/some-*.jar")
}
```

Comment: It's sad that why have to use this kind of hack to get this done.

Answer (score 26):

From the Gradle documentation

> The War plugin adds two dependency configurations: providedCompile and
>   providedRuntime. Those configurations have the same scope as the
>   respective compile and runtime configurations, except that they are
>   not added to the WAR archive.

So, in other words, **adding an entry to `providedCompile` or `providedRuntime` will cause that dependency to be excluded from the war file.**

- use `providedCompile` if you have source that relies on some classes for compiling
- use `providedRuntime` if you use it for testing and not compiling.

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html

**Example**

`providedCompile "javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5"`

Comment: Works:
    
    apply plugin: 'war'
    dependencies {
       runtime (project(':childProject')) {
       }
       providedCompile "javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api"
    }

Comment: I want to exclude a jar from the war due to file size reasons.  SpringBoot (which I'm using) unfortunately moves the jars to `WEB-INF/lib-provided` for the case of using an embedded server.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but when I changed the scope to "provided" instead of "providedComile/Runtime", then it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I realised that providedCompile sometimes introduced dependencies issues for me, e.g. some classes are not found. I then figured out a more flexible solution.

We can just configure required dependencies as 'compile' and then exclude specific jars from the war file by using the following war configuration:

```
war {
    classpath = classpath.filter { file ->
        println file.name
        (
            !file.name.startsWith('gwt-dev') &&
            !file.name.startsWith('gwt-user') &&
            !file.name.startsWith('guava-gwt') &&
            !file.name.startsWith('gwtbootstrap3') &&
            !file.name.startsWith('gwtbootstrap3-extras') &&
            !file.name.startsWith('servlet-api')
        )
    }
}
```

So far, I found this is the cleanest solution for me. I hope it helps.

Comment: I liked, this but this to me filtered out all values of that jar - i only wanted to remove duplicates.  https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1454 provided a solution similar that only excludes duplicates

Comment: I guess you will need to write some custom logic in it to remove duplicates. As you can see, we can print all file names

Comment: Yup, got it done and working as I wished, but yours put me on the right track to solve it, it's an odd case and it's only a problem temporarily until the other artifacts are put into maven and not just dropped into a lib dir.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but i found a generic solution based on the one of Jake W.

In your child-project, without the war plugin, you add your own providedCompile and providedRuntime like this:

```
configurations {
  providedCompile
  providedRuntime.extendsFrom providedCompile
}

plugins.withId('java') {
  configurations {
    compile.extendsFrom providedCompile
    runtime.extendsFrom providedRuntime
  }
}
```

In the project with your war file you copy this anywhere you want:

```
configurations.runtime.allDependencies.withType(ProjectDependency) { ProjectDependency dep ->
  Project proj = dep.dependencyProject
  evaluationDependsOn(proj.path)
  Configuration cfg = proj.configurations.findByName('providedRuntime')
  if (cfg != null){
    war {
      classpath -= cfg
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of the War task is to copy the content of src/main/webapp to the root of the archive. Your webapp directory may of course contain a WEB-INF sub-directory, which may contain all the dependencies of the runtime [1] configuration to WEB-INF/lib.

So to avoid load of other jar files or to decrease war file size, you may have to exclude jars during packaging. So, try adding **rootSpec.exclude("**/*.jar")** to exclude jars in war file like below.

```
war {
    archiveName = "newproject.war"
    rootSpec.exclude("**/*.jar")
    destinationDir = buildDir
}
```